# Lighttpd: How to link multiple domains to different tomcat web apps

Tags: tomcat7, lighttpd

I have two web apps running on tomcat: **zaibalo** and **demotivators**,
and I want them to be available on different domains: **zaibalo.com.ua** and **demotivators.com.ua**.
This is a not working **Lighttpd** configuration I have now:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "zaibalo.com.ua" {
server.document-root = "zaibalo",
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" =>
        ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8080 ) ) )
}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "demotivators.com.ua" {
server.document-root = "demotivators",
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" =>
        ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8080) ) )
}
```

Comment: If I correctly understand you want the following redirection : `http://zaibalo.com.ua/**` -> `http://localhost:8080/zaibabalo/**` on your host that allready responds to `zaibalo.com.ua` in DNS ?

Comment: Yes. At the moment http://zaibalo.com.ua/** -> http://localhost:8080/.
But I would like it to be http://zaibalo.com.ua/** -> http://localhost:8080/zaibalo and the second domain:
http://demotivators.com.ua/** -> http://localhost:8080/demotivators.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda went the other way:
I configured second host in Tomcat by editing conf/server.xml file:

```
<Host name="zaibalo.com.ua"  appBase="webapps1" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
        prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>

<Host name="demotivators.com.ua"  appBase="webapps2" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
        prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

Deployed my web applications both named as ROOT to separate directories: webapps1 and webapps2.
And also had to change the Connector port to 80:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

So there were no need in Lighttpd anymore. TA-DA-A-A-A-A!!!